# Node.js get all occurrences of a substring in a string

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, replace, substring

I have a string in Node.js Runtime e.g

```js
var content = "my content contain some URL like https://this.me/36gD6d3 or https://this.me/39Jwjd";
```

How can I read each `https://this.me/36gD6d3` and `https://this.me/39Jwjd` to replace it with another URL?

A `forEach` loop or something similar would be best. :-)

What I need is to make a request to each of that URL to get the real URL behind the shorten URL. That's not the problem.

---

Before and after each of that URLs is neither a `whitespace` or a `.`.
Domain `https://this.me/` is constant but the IDs `39Jwjd`, `36gD6d3` are changing.

Looking forward to your answers! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex to find occurrences of this URL.

```js
var content = "my content contain some URL like https://this.me/36gD6d3 or https://this.me/39Jwjd";
console.log(content.match(/https:\/\/this\.me\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/g))
```

This outputs:

```
[
  "https://this.me/36gD6d3",
  "https://this.me/39Jwjd"
]
```

In order to replace the found occurrences, use `replace()` function.

```js
var content = "my content contain some URL like https://this.me/36gD6d3 or https://this.me/39Jwjd";
console.log(content.replace(/https:\/\/this\.me\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/g, "<Replaced URL here>"))
```

Output:

```
my content contain some URL like <Replaced URL here> or <Replaced URL here>
```

If you want to replace the occurrences depending on the previous value, you could either use substitution or pass replacement function as the second argument.

Learn more on `String.prototype.replace` function at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Answer (score 1):

If you want your replace to be asynchronous *(which I'm guessing is the case when you lookup the full URL)*, you could do something like this:

```js
(async () => {
  const str = "my content contain some URL like https://this.me/36gD6d3 or https://this.me/39Jwjd",
        res = await replaceAllUrls(str);
  console.log(res);
})();

function replaceAllUrls(str) {
  const regex   = /https?:\/\/this\.me\/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+/g,
        matches = str.match(regex) || [];

  return Promise.all(matches.map(getFullUrl)).then(values => {
    return str.replace(regex, () => values.shift());
  });
}

function getFullUrl(u) {
  // Just for the demo, use your own
  return new Promise((r) => setTimeout(() => r(`{{Full URL of ${u}}}`), 100));
  // If it fails (you cannot get the full URL),
  // don't forget to catch the error and return the original URL!
}
```